# R - select column depending on available values

Tags: r, vectorization, logical-operators, idioms

I have x:

```
x = structure(c(12, 24, NA, 25), .Dim = c(2L, 2L))

> x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   12   NA
[2,]   24   25
```

and would like to return `y`, where `y` equals the value in the second column of `x` if the value is available, and the value in the first column if not.

so:

```
> y
[1] 12 25
```

I want to use the solution for a large array, so I am looking for a vectorized solution if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelse` does exactly what you want:

```
> ifelse(is.na(x[,2]), x[,1], x[,2])
[1] 12 25
```

If speed is paramount (and you don't want to mess with C), you can try:

```
y <- x[,2]
y[is.na(y)] <- x[is.na(y), 1]
```

This effectively shortcircuits some of the overhead of `ifelse`.  Consider:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- cbind(sample(1:1e5), sample(c(1:95000, rep(NA, 5000))))
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  z <- ifelse(is.na(x[,2]), x[,1], x[,2]),
  {y <- x[,2]; y[is.na(y)] <- x[is.na(y), 1]},
  times=10
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                                       expr        min  median
# z <- ifelse(is.na(x[, 2]), x[, 1], x[, 2])      30.46   33.06
# y <- x[, 2]; y[is.na(y)] <- x[is.na(y), 1]       5.48    5.77 
identical(y, z)    
# [1] TRUE
```